# missing values for each participant in the study

Tags: r, missing-data, subject

I am working in r, what I want to di is make a table or a graph that represents for each participant their missing values. i.e. I have 4700+ participants and for each questions there are between 20 -40 missings. I would like to represent the missing in such a way that I can see who are the people that did not answer the questions and possible look if there is a pattern in the missing values. I have done the following:

## Count of complete cases in a data frame named 'data'

```
sum(complete.cases(mydata))
```

## Count of incomplete cases

```
sum(!complete.cases(mydata$Variable1))
```

## Which cases (row numbers) are incomplete?

```
which(!complete.cases(mydata$Variable1))
```

I then got a list of numbers (That I am not quite sure how to interpret,at first I thought these were the patient numbers but then I noticed that this is not the case.)

I also tried making subsets with only the missings, but then I litterly only see how many missings there are but not **who** the missings are from.

Could somebody help me? Thanks!

Zas

Comment: Hello! Make a code reproducible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Give some data to make a point in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a column that can distinguish a row in the data.frame `mydata` say patient numbers `patient_no`, then you can easily find out the patient numbers of missing people by:

```
> mydata <- data.frame(patient_no = 1:5, variable1 = c(NA,NA,1,2,3))

> mydata[!complete.cases(mydata$variable1),'patient_no']

[1] 1 2
```

If you want to consider the pattern in which the users have missed a particular question, then this might be useful for you:

Assumption: Except Column 1, all other columns represent the columns related to questions.

```
> lapply(mydata[,-1],function(x){mydata[!complete.cases(x),'patient_no']})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it gives me an error saying "incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: Is mydata a data.frame?

Comment: mydata, is the data file where the values are in.

Comment: So, is it mydata.csv? or mydata stores the file name?

Comment: its an .sav file (I imported it from spss)

Comment: So, you need to first import the data using `read.spss()` function, convert to data.frame and then do the job.

Comment: You can convert the data to data.frame by setting parameter `to.data.frame` to `T` in `read.spss()` function.

Comment: now I get a message "unable to open file: 'No such file or directory" O tried downloading teh memsic package and chagning it using that but I still get the same message.

Comment: Please make sure that the file lies somewhere in the workspace. Or specify the complete path of the file.

Comment: I had to specify the complete path

Comment: Thank you so much Kunal!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that R automatically attach numbers to the observations in your data set. For example if your data has 20 observations (20 rows), R attaches numbers from 1 to 20, which is actually not part of your original data. **They are the row numbers.** The results produced by the R code: `which(!complete.cases(mydata$Variable1))` correspond to those numbers. The numbers are the rows of your data set that has at least one missing data (column).